# Value of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Date?)' cannot be converted to 'Date'

Tags: vb.net, linq, datetime

I'm trying to get datetime value but here is issue with nullable datetype. How to fix that?

```
Public Function GetDate(ByVal kodg As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim g = From dt In db.xDates _
            Join f In db.xGrafiks On dt.КодД Equals f.DateKod _
            Where f.Kod = kodg
            Select New Date?(dt.Дата) ???
    Return g ???
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g` will be a `IQueryable(Date?)`, which is a collection, so you first have to check if there is a value. You can do this by using `FirstOrDefault()` (if there can be multiple results or none), or `SingleOrDefault` (if there shouldn't be multiple resulst).

Then you get one `Date?` back. You can then use the `HasValue` property to check if the `Date?` has a value, if that's true just return it. If not you should return another `Date` from your function (maybe `DateTime.MinValue` ?).

Or you could change the return value of your function to be a `Date?` and the  just return the nullable date from your query.

Comment: Additionally, if there is a default date that can be used, you could use:
`Return if(g, <default value>)`
That is apparently how the coallesce operator manifests in VB.  If g is null, whatever <default value> is will be returned.